# iPhone SDK Simple Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

Is it possible to add a UIActivityIndicatorView to the left side of a UITableViewCell?  We're already using the right side of a UITableViewCell for a disclosure indicator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Just instantiate a UIActivityIndicatorView, give it a .frame that sets it where you want it, add it as a subview of cell.contentView, and call `startAnimating`.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)]; //or whatever--this will put it in the top left corner of the cell
[cell.contentView addSubview:spinner]
[spinner startAnimating];
[spinner release];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom cell, you can do anything you want. But [this document here from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15) should give you all you need whether just adding subviews to a regular old UITableViewCell or creating your own.